# pic18f4520 with picos18- interrupt problem

Tags: button, switch-statement, interrupt, pic

I am programming PIC18F4520, and using picos18 for multitasking. I need to control buttons with PORTB. I am using interrupts, but I am facing a problem.

Out of nowhere (while I am not pressing buttons), my interrupt handler executes. My pic handles many interrupts.

What could be the reason??

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell as which kind of hardware interrupt you are using!

I suppose on RB port change interrupt. So did you enable pull-ups resistors on PORTB? If you didn't than PORTB input pins have floating potential.